# Как повторить структуру папки?

Tags: c#

Есть папка и ее полный путь "С:\Temp". В данной папке есть вложенные папки и уровень вложений не известен. Есть другая папка, к примеру "D:\Folder1\Temp". Как быстро на основании первого пути создать такую же структуру подпапок во втором пути? Спасибо

Comment: А что означает слово «быстро» в вашем случае? Вы знаете какой-то _медленный_ путь, который вас по каким-то причинам не устраивает?

Comment: Быстро - понятие растяжимо. На тот случай,если кто-то сталкивался с этим и знает несколько вариантов решения этой задачи.

Comment: Рекурсивно пробегаемся по всем папкам из "С:\Temp", сохраняем их в памяти и опять же рекурсивно разворачиваем это всё дело в "D:\Folder1\Temp". Могу нарыть код рекурсивного сохранения папок, у меня где-то был, если нужно.

Comment: Как пример - было бы неплохо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё один пример для использования готовых утилит командной строки — утилита `robocopy` (входит в поставку Windows Vista+):

```
robocopy "С:\Temp" "D:\Folder1\Temp" /e /xf *
```

Ключ `/e` разрешает рекурсивное копирование каталогов, даже пустых.

Ключ `/xf *` отключает копирование файлов по маске `*`, то есть всех файлов.

(Решение, конечно, только под Windows.)

Comment: Vista+ [Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).

Comment: @nick_gabpe: И правда! Спасибо, исправлю.

Answer (score 2):

Самое просто- это создать процесс командной строки и вызвать [MD](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html) с нужными параметрами и структура будет создана.